# chart with Angular.js and D3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm try to make chart with angular.js but the chart don't apears in page the code works when run html page with out rout.js but when user rout.js  It display blank page
This is my code.

```
 var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularCharts']);
   function D3Controller($scope) {

console.log("Entering Scope");

$scope.config = {
    title: 'Products',
    tooltips: true,
    labels: false,
    mouseover: function () {
    },
    mouseout: function () {
    },
    click: function () {
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        //could be 'left, right'
        position: 'right'
    }
}
 console.log("And here we are in $scope." + $scope.config.title );
;

$scope.data = {
    series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards'],
    data: [{
            x: "Laptops",
            y: [100, 500, 0],
            tooltip: "this is tooltip"
        }, {
            x: "Desktops",
            y: [300, 100, 100]
        }, {
            x: "Mobiles",
            y: [351]
        }, {
            x: "Tablets",
            y: [54, 0, 879]
        }]


}
 console.log("And here we are in $scope.data.sereis" + $scope.data.series );
;

}
```

rout.js

```
  'use strict';

  myappApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/d3', {
                templateUrl: 'views/d3/d3.html',
                controller: 'D3Controller',

                access: {
                    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                }
            })
    });
```

html page

```
  <div ng-controller="D3Controller"  >
    <div id="d3-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; padding: 0px; position: relative;">
                <div 
                    data-ac-chart="'bar'" 
                    data-ac-data="data" 
                    data-ac-config="config" 
                    class="chart">
                </div>
                <input ng-model="config.title" style="width: 100%;"/>
                <br>
                <input ng-model="data.series" style="width: 100%;"/>
                <br>
                <input ng-model="data.data" style="width: 100%;"/>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: See console log (In firefox Ctrl+shift+k, in Chrome ctrl+shift+J -> Console). You mistyped in route.js `myappApp.config`should be `myapp.config`. You will see an error in console, add it to your question. BTW what is 'use strict' for?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered your `D3Controller` anywhere in your code but are referring to it as a string while declaring the route.

To fix the problem, if `D3Controller` is in the same scope as the `myApp.config` use the bare name of the function `D3Controller` instead of the string `"D3Controller"`.

Otherwise, register the controller with your app:

```
myApp.controller('D3Controller', D3Controller);
```